# Compiling c with mysql api in Windows

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I am using cygwin gcc compiler to compile c code.
I have c code that fetches the data from database using mysql connector api.

Once i was able to compile and run it by linking libmysql library, now i sort of facing issue to compile.

I am getting error saying undefined reference to mysql_ini.

I used fallowing commands

```
gcc myfile.c -l libmysql
```

For this i got error saying that libmysql file cannot be found.

So i placed my source code and libmysql library in same folder, then issued fallowing command

```
 gcc myfile.c -L. -l libmysql
```

This time i got same undefined error.

Comment: Try `gcc myfile.c -L. -lmysql` or `gcc myfile.c -lmysql`

Comment: @MichaelWalz but mysql library name is libmysql

Comment: Try it anyway   .

Comment: I tried and got " can't find mysql "

Comment: If you use the `-l somename` then the linker will search for a file `libsomename.so`. If the shared lib file name is `libmysql.so` then you only need to use `-l mysql`. Running `mysql_config --libs` shows me that the `-l`  option should be `-lmysqlclient`. It's better to compile it the way as shown in Marcos Dalte's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like it:

```
$ gcc version.c -o version  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

More information in http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. for me this worked out:

1. create test.c

```c
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
  exit(0);
}
```

2. install mysql (admin required)

```
choco install mysql
```

3. compile

```
gcc -o test.exe test.c -IC:/tools/mysql/current/include C:/tools/mysql/current/lib/libmysql.dll
```

4. set system path for lib

```
# CMD for session
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\tools\mysql\current\lib\

# OR
# powershell session
$env:Path += ";C:\tools\mysql\current\lib\"
```

5. run

```
.\test.exe
```